# Session is closed! Spring + JPA (HIbernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, session, exceção

Estou tentando fazer um exemplo de `JPA` + `Spring`.

Mas estou com problema ao gerenciar transações.

**persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TwsPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>model.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="
true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<!-- ANNOTATIONS POUR AOP -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- ANNOTATIONS POUR LA CREATION DE BEANS -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tws" />

    <!-- Datasource -->
    <bean name="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql:/localhost:5432/tecwebsoft" />
        <property name="username" value="p" />
        <property name="password" value="a" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="TwsPersistence" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="false"/>


    <bean id="genericDAO" class="com.tws.persistence.dao.GenericDAO"></bean>
```

**DAO.java:**

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

        @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public <T> List<T> load(Class<T> classe) {
        try {
            DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(classe);
            // manager.getTransaction().begin();
            Session sessao = (Session) manager.getDelegate();

            System.out.println("Manager: " + manager);
            System.out.println("Sessão: " + sessao);


            Criteria criteria = dc.getExecutableCriteria(sessao);

            return criteria.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Falha");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
Sessão: SessionImpl(<closed>)
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1688)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at com.tws.persistence.dao.GenericDAO.load(GenericDAO.java:64)
    at Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Quando mando listar ele me da a exception, session is close.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi.

Retirando o datasource do spring, deixando apenas o JPA(persistence.xml).

Qualquer coisa posto os códigos.

Abrçss

> Persistence

```
    <persistence-unit name="TwsPersistence"
            transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>


            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                    value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tecwebsoft" />

                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />


                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
```

> Spring Context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tecWebSoft" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="TwsPersistence" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tecWebSoft" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        proxy-target-class="false" />
```

> Generic DAO

```
    @PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;
```